# How to run certain task every day at a particular time using ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, timertask, background-thread, scheduledexecutorservice

I am trying to run a certain task everyday at 5 AM in the morning. So I decided to use `ScheduledExecutorService` for this but so far I have seen examples which shows how to run task every few minutes.

And I am not able to find any example which shows how to run a task every day at a particular time (5 AM) in the morning and also considering the fact of daylight saving time as well -

Below is my code which will run every 15 minutes -

```
public class ScheduledTaskExample {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
        .newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void startScheduleTask() {
    /**
    * not using the taskHandle returned here, but it can be used to cancel
    * the task, or check if it's done (for recurring tasks, that's not
    * going to be very useful)
    */
    final ScheduledFuture<?> taskHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    getDataFromDatabase();
                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); //or loggger would be better
                }
            }
        }, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    private void getDataFromDatabase() {
        System.out.println("getting data...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledTaskExample ste = new ScheduledTaskExample();
        ste.startScheduleTask();
    }
}
```

Is there any way, I can schedule a task to run every day 5 AM in the morning using `ScheduledExecutorService` considering the fact of daylight saving time as well?

And also `TimerTask` is better for this or `ScheduledExecutorService`?

Comment: Use something like Quartz instead.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

As with the present java SE 8 release with it's excellent date time API with `java.time` these kind of calculation can be done more easily instead of using    `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date`.

- Use [date time class's i.e. LocalDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) of this new API
- Use [ZonedDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class to handle Time Zone specific calculation including Daylight Saving issues. You will find [tutorial and example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html) here.

Now as a sample example for scheduling a task with your use case:

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
ZonedDateTime nextRun = now.withHour(5).withMinute(0).withSecond(0);
if(now.compareTo(nextRun) > 0)
    nextRun = nextRun.plusDays(1);

Duration duration = Duration.between(now, nextRun);
long initialDelay = duration.getSeconds();

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);            
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunnableTask(),
    initialDelay,
    TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1),
    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The `initialDelay` is computed to ask the scheduler to delay the execution in `TimeUnit.SECONDS`. Time difference issues with unit milliseconds and below seems to be negligible for this use case. But you can still make use of `duration.toMillis()` and `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS` for handling the scheduling computaions in milliseconds.

> And also TimerTask is better for this or ScheduledExecutorService?

**NO:** `ScheduledExecutorService` seemingly better than `TimerTask`. [StackOverflow has already an answer for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice).

From @PaddyD,

> You still have the issue whereby you need to restart this twice a year
> if you want it to run at the right local time. scheduleAtFixedRate
> won't cut it unless you are happy with the same UTC time all year.

As it is true and @PaddyD already has given a workaround(+1 to him), I am providing a working example with Java8 date time API with `ScheduledExecutorService`. [**Using daemon thread is dangerous**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java#answer-2213443)

```
class MyTaskExecutor
{
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    MyTask myTask;
    volatile boolean isStopIssued;

    public MyTaskExecutor(MyTask myTask$) 
    {
        myTask = myTask$;
        
    }
    
    public void startExecutionAt(int targetHour, int targetMin, int targetSec)
    {
        Runnable taskWrapper = new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                myTask.execute();
                startExecutionAt(targetHour, targetMin, targetSec);
            }
            
        };
        long delay = computeNextDelay(targetHour, targetMin, targetSec);
        executorService.schedule(taskWrapper, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private long computeNextDelay(int targetHour, int targetMin, int targetSec) 
    {
        LocalDateTime localNow = LocalDateTime.now();
        ZoneId currentZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        ZonedDateTime zonedNow = ZonedDateTime.of(localNow, currentZone);
        ZonedDateTime zonedNextTarget = zonedNow.withHour(targetHour).withMinute(targetMin).withSecond(targetSec);
        if(zonedNow.compareTo(zonedNextTarget) > 0)
            zonedNextTarget = zonedNextTarget.plusDays(1);
        
        Duration duration = Duration.between(zonedNow, zonedNextTarget);
        return duration.getSeconds();
    }
    
    public void stop()
    {
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyTaskExecutor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- `MyTask` is an interface with function `execute`.
- While stopping `ScheduledExecutorService`, Always use `awaitTermination` after invoking `shutdown` on it: There's always a likelihood your task is stuck / deadlocking and the user would wait forever.

The previous example I gave with Calender was just an *idea* which I did mention, I avoided exact time calculation and Daylight saving issues. Updated the solution on per the complain of @PaddyD

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, can you please explain me in detail how `intDelayInHour` means that I will be running my task at 5 AM in the morning?

Comment: What is the purpose of aDate?

Comment: But if you start this at HH:mm the task will be run at 05:mm as opposed to 5am? It also doesn't account for daylight saving time as OP requested.

Ok if you start it immediately after the hour, or if you're happy with any time between 5 and 6, or if you don't mind restarting the application in the middle of the night twice a year after the clocks have changed I suppose...

Comment: You still have the issue whereby you need to restart this twice a year if you want it to run at the right local time. `scheduleAtFixedRate` won't cut it unless you are happy with the same UTC time all year.

Comment: Why does the following example (second) trigger execute n times or till the second passes? Wasn't the code suppose to trigger task once every day?

Comment: Maybe this is different question, can we achieve same results with JobScheduler

Comment: This does not seem to work if the computer hibernates. The initial delay is frozen until the computer wakes up, then the task happens at the wrong time.

Comment: This example solution still does not work correctly if you are trying to run something (that runs very quickly) right after or at midnight.  It has (at least 2) problems - it may trigger before midnight, because the scheduled executor isn't exact, and, when it does trigger, it runs and runs and runs, usually 999 times - once every ms until the next ms happens.  Still looking for a proper solution....

Comment: Best is to run a fast (and inaccurate) timer (I chose every 4 seconds) and fire the event when the current time exceeds `nextRun`, then update `nextRun` for the next occurrence. Something like this: `private void scheduleNext(){LocalDateTime now=LocalDateTime.now();nextRun=now.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).plusHours(5);if(nextRun.compareTo(now)<=0)nextRun=nextRun.plus(1,ChronoUnit.DAYS);}`

Answer (score 32):

In Java 8:

```
scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

//Change here for the hour you want ----------------------------------.at()       
Long midnight=LocalDateTime.now().until(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(), ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, midnight, 1440, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: For readability I would suggest `TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(1)` instead of the "magic number" 1440.

Comment: Thanks, Victor. In this way need to restart twice a year if I want it to run at the right local time?

Comment: the fixed rate should not change when local time changes, after created, it becomes about the rate.

Comment: How come this triggers my task at 23:59:59?

Comment: For readability I would suggest 1 instead of either 1440 or TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(1), and then use the time unit TimeUnit.DAYS.  ;-)

Comment: Why would you make a thread pool with only 1 thread inside it?

Comment: @invzbl3 — You're right, since this doesn't account for the 23/25 hour days that occur yearly at the daylight saving time cutover (or whatever amount the daylight time shift may be).

Comment: This code fails to account to anomalies such as Daylight Savings Time (DST) imposed by politicians on a region’s timekeeping. The `LocalDateTime` class is exactly the wrong class to be using as it purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to be honest, it's so much more clear and simple compared to the other one

Comment: @Displee Because this code is only going to run a single task at a periodic interval. It is not going to run multiple tasks in parallel, so the other threads would never be used.

Comment: This is a great example. Although I wonder why the `midnight` value is boxed.

Comment: On `1 TimeUnit.DAYS`, it turns out you have to use the same TimeUnit for both the initial delay and the period.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have the luxury of being able to use Java 8, the following will do what you need:

```
public class DailyRunnerDaemon
{
   private final Runnable dailyTask;
   private final int hour;
   private final int minute;
   private final int second;
   private final String runThreadName;

   public DailyRunnerDaemon(Calendar timeOfDay, Runnable dailyTask, String runThreadName)
   {
      this.dailyTask = dailyTask;
      this.hour = timeOfDay.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
      this.minute = timeOfDay.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      this.second = timeOfDay.get(Calendar.SECOND);
      this.runThreadName = runThreadName;
   }

   public void start()
   {
      startTimer();
   }

   private void startTimer();
   {
      new Timer(runThreadName, true).schedule(new TimerTask()
      {
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
            dailyTask.run();
            startTimer();
         }
      }, getNextRunTime());
   }


   private Date getNextRunTime()
   {
      Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
      startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
      startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
      startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
      startTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

      if(startTime.before(now) || startTime.equals(now))
      {
         startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
      }

      return startTime.getTime();
   }
}
```

It doesn't require any external libs, and will account for daylight savings. Simply pass in the time of day you want to run the task as a `Calendar` object, and the task as a `Runnable`. For example:

```
Calendar timeOfDay = Calendar.getInstance();
timeOfDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
timeOfDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
timeOfDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

new DailyRunnerDaemon(timeOfDay, new Runnable()
{
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      try
      {
        // call whatever your daily task is here
        doHousekeeping();
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        logger.error("An error occurred performing daily housekeeping", e);
      }
   }
}, "daily-housekeeping");
```

N.B. the timer task runs in a Daemon thread which is not recommended for doing any IO. If you need to use a User thread, you will need to add another method which cancels the timer.

If you have to use a `ScheduledExecutorService`, simply change the `startTimer` method to the following:

```
private void startTimer()
{
   Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().schedule(new Runnable()
   {
      Thread.currentThread().setName(runThreadName);
      dailyTask.run();
      startTimer();
   }, getNextRunTime().getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis(),
   TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

I am not sure of the behaviour but you may need a stop method which calls `shutdownNow` if you go down the `ScheduledExecutorService` route, otherwise your application may hang when you try to stop it.

Comment: I got your point. +1 and thank you. However, it is better if we don't use Daemon thread(i.e., `new Timer(runThreadName, true)`).

Comment: @Sage no worries. A daemon thread is fine if you're not doing any IO. The use case I wrote this for was just a simple fire-and-forget class for kicking off some threads to perform some daily housekeeping tasks. I suppose if you are performing database reads in the timer task thread as OP's request might indicate, then you shouldn't use a Daemon and will need some kind of stop method which you will have to call to enable your application to terminate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067578/when-are-daemon-threads-useful

Comment: @PaddyD Was the last part i.e the one using ScheduledExecutorSerive correct??? The way the anonymous class is created doesnt look correct syntax wise. Also newSingleThreadExecutor() wouldnt have schedule method right??

Comment: If someone is stuck on Java 6 & 7, I would suggest they instead use the back-port of most of the *java.time* functionality. See the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered using something like [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)?  This library has a mechanism for scheduling tasks to run at a set period of time every day using a cron like expression (take a look at `CronScheduleBuilder`).

Some example code (not tested):

```
public class GetDatabaseJob implements InterruptableJob
{
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException
    {
        getFromDatabase();
    }
}

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JobDetails job = JobBuilder.newJob(GetDatabaseJob.class);

        // Schedule to run at 5 AM every day
        ScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder = 
                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 5 * * ?");
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().
                withSchedule(scheduleBuilder).build();

        Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        scheduler.start();
    }
}
```

There's a bit more work upfront, and you may need to rewrite your job execution code, but it should give you more control over how you want you job to run.  Also it would be easier to change the schedule should you need to.

Answer (score 6):

**Java8:**
My upgrage version from top answer:

1. Fixed situation when Web Application Server doens't want to stop, because of threadpool with idle thread
2. Without recursion
3. Run task with your custom local time, in my case, it's Belarus, Minsk

```
/**
 * Execute {@link AppWork} once per day.
 * <p>
 * Created by aalexeenka on 29.12.2016.
 */
public class OncePerDayAppWorkExecutor {

    private static final Logger LOG = AppLoggerFactory.getScheduleLog(OncePerDayAppWorkExecutor.class);

    private ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    private final String name;
    private final AppWork appWork;

    private final int targetHour;
    private final int targetMin;
    private final int targetSec;

    private volatile boolean isBusy = false;
    private volatile ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledTask = null;

    private AtomicInteger completedTasks = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public OncePerDayAppWorkExecutor(
            String name,
            AppWork appWork,
            int targetHour,
            int targetMin,
            int targetSec
    ) {
        this.name = "Executor [" + name + "]";
        this.appWork = appWork;

        this.targetHour = targetHour;
        this.targetMin = targetMin;
        this.targetSec = targetSec;
    }

    public void start() {
        scheduleNextTask(doTaskWork());
    }

    private Runnable doTaskWork() {
        return () -> {
            LOG.info(name + " [" + completedTasks.get() + "] start: " + minskDateTime());
            try {
                isBusy = true;
                appWork.doWork();
                LOG.info(name + " finish work in " + minskDateTime());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOG.error(name + " throw exception in " + minskDateTime(), ex);
            } finally {
                isBusy = false;
            }
            scheduleNextTask(doTaskWork());
            LOG.info(name + " [" + completedTasks.get() + "] finish: " + minskDateTime());
            LOG.info(name + " completed tasks: " + completedTasks.incrementAndGet());
        };
    }

    private void scheduleNextTask(Runnable task) {
        LOG.info(name + " make schedule in " + minskDateTime());
        long delay = computeNextDelay(targetHour, targetMin, targetSec);
        LOG.info(name + " has delay in " + delay);
        scheduledTask = executorService.schedule(task, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private static long computeNextDelay(int targetHour, int targetMin, int targetSec) {
        ZonedDateTime zonedNow = minskDateTime();
        ZonedDateTime zonedNextTarget = zonedNow.withHour(targetHour).withMinute(targetMin).withSecond(targetSec).withNano(0);

        if (zonedNow.compareTo(zonedNextTarget) > 0) {
            zonedNextTarget = zonedNextTarget.plusDays(1);
        }

        Duration duration = Duration.between(zonedNow, zonedNextTarget);
        return duration.getSeconds();
    }

    public static ZonedDateTime minskDateTime() {
        return ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Minsk"));
    }

    public void stop() {
        LOG.info(name + " is stopping.");
        if (scheduledTask != null) {
            scheduledTask.cancel(false);
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        LOG.info(name + " stopped.");
        try {
            LOG.info(name + " awaitTermination, start: isBusy [ " + isBusy + "]");
            // wait one minute to termination if busy
            if (isBusy) {
                executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            LOG.error(name + " awaitTermination exception", ex);
        } finally {
            LOG.info(name + " awaitTermination, finish");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have similar requirement. I have to schedule task for a day at given time. Once scheduled task completes, schedule task for next day at given time. This should continue to go on.My question is how to find out scheduled task has completed or not. Once I know scheduled task has completed then only I can schedule for next day.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I had to schedule bunch of tasks that should be executed during a day using `ScheduledExecutorService`. 
This was solved by one task starting at 3:30 AM scheduling all other tasks relatively to his **current time**. And rescheduling himself for the next day at 3:30 AM.

With this scenario daylight savings are not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple date parse, if the time of the day is before now, let's start tomorrow :

```
  String timeToStart = "12:17:30";
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss");
  SimpleDateFormat formatOnlyDay = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  Date now = new Date();
  Date dateToStart = format.parse(formatOnlyDay.format(now) + " at " + timeToStart);
  long diff = dateToStart.getTime() - now.getTime();
  if (diff < 0) {
    // tomorrow
    Date tomorrow = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(tomorrow);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    tomorrow = c.getTime();
    dateToStart = format.parse(formatOnlyDay.format(tomorrow) + " at " + timeToStart);
    diff = dateToStart.getTime() - now.getTime();
  }

  ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);            
  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunnableTask(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff) ,
                                  24*60*60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below class to schedule your task every day particular time

```
package interfaces;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CronDemo implements Runnable{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Long delayTime;

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        final Long initialDelay = LocalDateTime.now().until(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).atTime(12, 30), ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

        if (initialDelay > TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(1)) {
            delayTime = LocalDateTime.now().until(LocalDate.now().atTime(12, 30), ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        } else {
            delayTime = initialDelay;
        }

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new CronDemo(), delayTime, TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(1), TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I am your job executin at:" + new Date());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use the outdated `Date` and `TimeUnit` in 2019

Answer (score 2):

What if your server goes down at 4:59AM and comes back at 5:01AM? I think it will just skip the run. I would recommend persistent scheduler like Quartz, that would store its schedule data somewhere. Then it will see that this run hasn't been performed yet and will do it at 5:01AM.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add up on [Victor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25120314/9553376).

I would recommend to add a check to see, if the variable (in his case the long `midnight`) is higher than `1440`. If it is, I would omit the `.plusDays(1)`, otherwise the task will only run the day after tomorrow.

I did it simply like this:

```
Long time;

final Long tempTime = LocalDateTime.now().until(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).atTime(7, 0), ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
if (tempTime > 1440) {
    time = LocalDateTime.now().until(LocalDate.now().atTime(7, 0), ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
} else {
    time = tempTime;
}
```

Comment: It simplifies if you make use of `truncatedTo()`

Answer (score 1):

The following example work for me

```
public class DemoScheduler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a calendar instance
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Set time of execution. Here, we have to run every day 4:20 PM; so,
        // setting all parameters.
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

        Long currentTime = new Date().getTime();

        // Check if current time is greater than our calendar's time. If So,
        // then change date to one day plus. As the time already pass for
        // execution.
        if (calendar.getTime().getTime() < currentTime) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        // Calendar is scheduled for future; so, it's time is higher than
        // current time.
        long startScheduler = calendar.getTime().getTime() - currentTime;

        // Setting stop scheduler at 4:21 PM. Over here, we are using current
        // calendar's object; so, date and AM_PM is not needed to set
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

        // Calculation stop scheduler
        long stopScheduler = calendar.getTime().getTime() - currentTime;

        // Executor is Runnable. The code which you want to run periodically.
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("test");
            }
        };

        // Get an instance of scheduler
        final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        // execute scheduler at fixed time.
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, startScheduler, stopScheduler, MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

reference:
https://chynten.wordpress.com/2016/06/03/java-scheduler-to-run-every-day-on-specific-time/

Answer (score 0):

Why to complicate a situation if you can just write like it? (yes -> low cohesion, hardcoded -> but it is a example and unfortunately with imperative way). For additional info read code example at below ;))

```
package timer.test;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class TestKitTimerWithExecuterService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestKitTimerWithExecuterService.class);

    private static final ScheduledExecutorService executorService 
= Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();// equal to => newScheduledThreadPool(1)/ Executor service with one Thread

    private static ScheduledFuture<?> future; // why? because scheduleAtFixedRate will return you it and you can act how you like ;)



    public static void main(String args[]){

        log.info("main thread start");

        Runnable task = () -> log.info("******** Task running ********");

        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

        LocalDateTime whenToStart = LocalDate.now().atTime(20, 11); // hour, minute

        Duration duration = Duration.between(now, whenToStart);

        log.info("WhenToStart : {}, Now : {}, Duration/difference in second : {}",whenToStart, now, duration.getSeconds());

        future = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task
                , duration.getSeconds()    //  difference in second - when to start a job
                ,2                         // period
                , TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        try {
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);  // DanDig imitation of reality
            cancelExecutor();    // after canceling Executor it will never run your job again
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info("main thread end");
    }




    public static void cancelExecutor(){

        future.cancel(true);
        executorService.shutdown();

        log.info("Executor service goes to shut down");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, it is assumed that code is running on single VM. This scheduler code will run multiple times if the code is running on multiple VMs. That has to be   handled separately.

Comment: Your post is more a comment than an actual answer to the problem.

Comment: Yes you are correct but I dont have permission to comment on the main answer so I have to comment like this only.