# Forcing refresh at specific time Guava Cache

Tags: caching, timer, guava, google-guava-cache

I'm trying to get this cache to refresh every day at 3AM. The problem is that users are having to wait a long time for the cache to warm up. So I would rather it be refreshed overnight and be ready to quickly access in the morning for the UI.

```
    return CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .expireAfterAccess(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .build(new CacheLoader<String, Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long load(String key)
                        throws Exception {
                        return db.getMetrics(key);
                }
            });
```

I want to be able to provide a fixed set of keys in the cache to refresh at 3AM.

I read the [Google documentation](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) but it seems like that only refreshes data that's already been loaded in the cache.

TL;DR - Looking to warm up the cache with a fixed set of keys at a specific time during the day

Comment: Generally you'd have a background thread scheduled to prefetch data, but often that exceeds the size of a local cache. In that case you would instead warm up a remote caching tier (e.g. memcached) which makes local cache misses inexpensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell Guava doesn't have anything built-in to "freshen"/"warm" values for a set of keys at some scheduled time but you can easily do it on your own.

**Warming the Cache**

You can warm your cash by simply calling `getAll(Iterable)` on your `LoadingCache<String, Long>` instance. e.g.

```
loadingCache.getAll(keysToFreshen);
```

Where `keysToFreshen` is an instance of `Iterable<String>` containing the keys you want to freshen at 3 AM (or whenever) (e.g. a `Set<String>`).

**Running the Cache Warming Code with a Job/Task Scheduler**

You now simply need to run `loadingCache.getAll(keysToFreshen)` using a tool to schedule a job/task at 3AM. You can use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), [Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/), Java's [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20388073/3255152) for an example), etc.