# Repeat scheduled task every day and hour

Tags: java, spring, task, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I have a job and I need to run every day at a certain time.

What i need?

```
    @BusinessObject("mail")
    @EnableScheduling
    public class MailImpl implements Mail {

        private @Log Logger log;

        private @Inject MailService mailService;

        @Override
        @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000000, initialDelay = 30000000)
        public void sendMails() {

            //TODO send emails

                }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run certain task every day at a particular time using ScheduledExecutorService?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387881/how-to-run-certain-task-every-day-at-a-particular-time-using-scheduledexecutorse)