# Scala/Java Executor Service start at specific time of day

Tags: java, scala, executorservice

I want to schedule a task to run only at a specific time of the day. Whats the easiest way to do this? I could probably use the Timer, TimerTask classes, but I was wondering if I could do the same with ExecutorService.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to use a script rather than Java or Scala.

Comment: Note that if this task is going to run from multiple machines, then any only in-memory tracking technique may lead to race condition. Avoiding that will require state tracking by your application using some tools like Quartz as Joe pointed out, or your own logic

Comment: You can use `ScheduledExecutorService`. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387881/how-to-run-certain-task-every-day-at-a-particular-time-using-scheduledexecutorse

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org). But it may also be on the heavy side if your needs are simple.