# execute a method only if the time is elapsed without using timer in java

Tags: java

I want to execute a method in a class say every day only once . If in a day already executed just return  or else execute the method.

I want to know what happens if I exit the code will it be running in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that **you already know how to schedule a task** to [run daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387881/how-to-run-certain-task-every-day-at-a-particular-time-using-scheduledexecutorse) 
the trick becomes knowing if the task has already run in that day without being prompted by the schedule.

For the desired behavior you will need to **save a time-stamp** (either as a variable in the java environment or as a file on the disk) of the most recent run, checking it before updating it and executing the function.

Some psuedocode:

```
Static bool timeManager(){
   CurrentTime = getCurrentTime()
   TimeStamp = getTimeStamp()
   if(CurrentTime - TimeStamp > 1day-afewMinutes){
        UpdateTimeStamp(CurrentTime)
        return true
   }else{
        return false
   }
}
void jobWrapper(){
    if timeManager(){
        doTheJob()
    }else{
        log("Skipping job at "+currentTime+" because job ran "+lastTime)
    }
}
```

Edit: rollback pointed out race condition so I put the time manager in a static method. Also I realized that rounding to the second might bone you so I figured I would subtract a few minutes from the whole day to avoid tasks scheduled on 24 hour intervals from blocking each-other due to rounding...

Comment: Keep in mind that your pseudocode is a race condition if he uses multiple threads

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. 
You can use sth like Cron job. The expression is guided here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm

Or you can use Quartz: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Or use `@Scheduled` from Spring https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Hope this help.