# Threads are not closing automatically

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

The started threads looks like not closing even after return from run(). In the left panel of Netbeans, it shows many number of "pool-xx-thread-1-running" and is increasing each time thread is executed. Below is my code:

// listen for operations
        client.subscribe("/location/#", new IMqttMessageListener() {
            public void messageArrived (final String topic, final MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                final String payload = new String(message.getPayload());

```
            System.out.println("Received operation " + payload);
            if (payload.startsWith("{\"location\":")) {
                // execute the operation in another thread to allow the MQTT client to
                // finish processing this message and acknowledge receipt to the server
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if(payload.equals("")) return;

                        try {
                            JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(payload, JsonObject.class);
                            String fixTime="", vehicleid="", deviceTime="", lat="", lon="", speed="",alt="", accuracy="", bearing="";
                            try{
                                String locationStr=jsonObject.get("location").toString();
                                locationStr=locationStr.substring(1, locationStr.length()-1).trim();
                                locationStr=locationStr.replace("\\", "");
                                JsonObject locationJson = new Gson().fromJson(locationStr, JsonObject.class);
                                try{
                                    long millis = Long.parseLong(locationJson.get("mTime").toString());
                                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    cal.setTimeInMillis(millis);
                                    fixTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
                                }catch(Exception ex){

                                }

                                lat=locationJson.get("mLatitude").toString();
                                lon=locationJson.get("mLongitude").toString();
                                alt=locationJson.get("mAltitude").toString();
                                speed=locationJson.get("mSpeed").toString();
                                accuracy=locationJson.get("mAccuracy").toString();
                                bearing=locationJson.get("mBearing").toString();
                            }catch(Exception ex){
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            try{
                                String entityStr = jsonObject.get("entity").toString();
                                JsonObject entityJson = new Gson().fromJson(entityStr, JsonObject.class);
                                vehicleid = entityJson.get("id").toString();
                                vehicleid = vehicleid.replace("\"", "");
                            }catch(Exception ex){
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            try{
                                String headerStr=jsonObject.get("header").toString();
                                JsonObject headerJson = new Gson().fromJson(headerStr, JsonObject.class);
                                String deviceTimeMsStr = headerJson.get("timestamp").toString();
                                long msTime = Long.parseLong(deviceTimeMsStr);
                                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                cal.setTimeInMillis(msTime);
                                deviceTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
                            }catch(Exception ex){
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Connection conn = null;
                            Statement stmt = null;
                            try{
                                String SQL = "INSERT INTO positions(protocol, deviceid, devicetime, fixtime, valid, latitude, longitude, altitude, speed, course, address, attributes, accuracy, network)";
                                SQL += " VALUES('osmand',(SELECT id FROM devices WHERE uniqueid = '" + vehicleid + "'),'" + deviceTime + "','" + fixTime + "',1," + lat + "," + lon + "," + alt + "," + speed + "," + bearing + ",'',''," + accuracy + ",'')";

                                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                                conn =DriverManager.getConnection(MYSQL_SERVERURL, MYSQL_USERID, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
                                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                                stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
                                System.out.println("Executed " + SQL);
                                return;
                            }catch(Exception ex){
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }finally {
                                try {
                                    if(stmt != null)
                                        conn.close();
                                } catch(SQLException se) {
                                }
                                try {
                                    if(conn != null)
                                        conn.close();
                                } catch(SQLException se) {
                                    se.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }catch(Exception ex){
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally{
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRCrH.png)

Comment: Strip your code down to the bare minimum needed to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you study the *Executors* tutorial by Oracle. And search Stack Overflow for many existing Questions and Answers on this topic.

## Create executor service only once

Do not repeatedly call `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`. Each call is creating a thread pool. You are never shutting them down. The threads continue, possibly even after your app terminates.

You should be *instantiating the executor service only once* in your app (generally). Then save the returned `ScheduledExecutorService` object somewhere in your app.

When you have a task to be run on a background thread, retrieve that existing object and schedule the task.

Eventually you must shut down the executor (with its backing thread pool).

For more discussion, see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60973593/642706) of mine on a very similar Question.

## `ScheduledExecutorService` is for scheduling

You are not scheduling your tasks with a delay. So you do not need a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

You need only an `ExecutorService` with a `submit` method.

Answer (score 0):

executorService.shutdown(); solved the problem like below

ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
});

executorService.shutdown();