# ManagedSchedulerExecutorService class in java

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduler, executorservice

I have to run a particular Java class at 5pm daily. I am trying to use `ManagedSchedulerExecutorService` class.

But using this class I can start job after initial delay and then at specific interval.

I want my job to be triggered at 5pm daily. Is this possible using some coding?

Is there any way to do that? Can any other API help me?

I am not allowed to use third party libraries. only Java APIs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run certain task every day at a particular time using ScheduledExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387881/how-to-run-certain-task-every-day-at-a-particular-time-using-scheduledexecutorse)

Comment: thank you @PhilipWrage

Comment: How can I use ManagedScheduledExecutorService  ?

Comment: @Rohitjha  I am still looking for Answer