# running a backup .bat file every day

Tags: batch-file, backup

```
@echo off
d:
cd mljewel.12
rar a -r mlyedek.rar
cd\
f
cd yedek
md %1
z:
cd yedek
md %1
copy D:\MLJEWEL.12\mlyedek.rar f:\yedek\%1
copy D:\MLJEWEL.12\mlyedek.rar z:\yedek\%1 
del D:\MLJEWEL.12\mlyedek.rar
pause
```

hello i have bat file saved as backup.bat and i have to run this file every day with date tagged with it. So what i do is I press win+R and write "backup 06062022" date goes to %1 in the code and a folder named 06062022 gets created.
basicly what i need is to backup a certain folder everyday on startup with any indication that contains the date

Comment: Your could run the script with ScheduledExecutorService, you could look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387881/how-to-run-certain-task-every-day-at-a-particular-time-using-scheduledexecutorse

Comment: use a scheduled task for "run each day at startup" and [get the date from the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727114/batch-command-date-and-time-in-file-name/18024049#18024049). Tip: use ISO format `YYYYMMDD` so your backup folders are properly sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "Datestamp="
set /a Datestamp=%1 2>nul
if not defined Datestamp (
 for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_localtime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %%x
 set /a DateStamp=Year*10000+Month*100+Day
)
```

then

```
d:
```

etc., etc. from your code, but replace `%1` with `%Datestamp%`

How it works:

The `setlocal` ensures that changes made to the environment are discarded when the batch ends.

The first `set` of `datestamp` "sets" the value to *nothing*, which causes `datestamp` to be undefined.

If you supply a parameter, this will be used for your datestamp. If you don't, an error message will be produced which will be suppressed by the `2>nul` and `datestamp` will remain undefined.

If `datestamp` is undefined, the `for` instruction runs `wmic` and picks those lines that contain `=` using `find` (the `^` "escapes" the pipe `|` and tells `cmd` that `|` is part of the parenthesised instruction, not of the `for`)

This will produce something like

```
Day=12
DayOfWeek=0
Hour=18
Milliseconds=
Minute=1
Month=6
Quarter=2
Second=47
WeekInMonth=3
Year=2022
```

and these variables will be `set` by the `set` instruction that the `for` executes.

Then calculate the datestamp as YYYYMMDD (20220612)

It's to your advantage that the date is expressed in this manner as the directories then produced will be listed by `dir` sorted in order. using the format you suggest will not do this and is confusing. Is `06062022` in MMDDYYYY order, or DDMMYYYY order, for instance?

So - these revisions will allow the batch to be run as it always has run, but omitting the parameter will cause it to calculate the current date and use that.

Then you can use `task scheduker` to eun the batch with no parameter and it all proceeds automagically.